# database ip visitor counter

Tags: database, ip, counter, visitor-pattern

this site is very helpful
thanks for all who answering questions..

i need an ip visitor counter and save the number in a table in database for each page..is there is an already script if so somebody till me it's name

if not is there any php/mysql code!!?
thankx

Answer (score 0):

although it wont store in data your own database (which may be good for performance of your site). have you checked out [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)?